# Azure B2C login hint is not correct

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an azure b2c custom flow. Everything works fine except when the user clicks the login button a hint shows up attached to the username that say “please match the requested format”. Why is this showing up? I don’t see anywhere in the base/extensions/ signup in files that has this restriction or message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, the problem was related to the claim type.  In my TrustFrameworkExtensions file, I needed to define a claimtype to override the default behavior.  The required changes was to add a restrictions setting and HelpText.  Something like this:

```
<ClaimType Id="signInName">
  <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserHelpText />
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" HelpText="Invalid username bro" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: I had stuck with changeSignInName Policy customization hack, This hints me the culprit. Thanks